# Finding the degree of rotation with respect to the original image

Tags: python, image, opencv, rotation, angle

I have two versions of an image. One image is not rotated, while the other image is rotated. How can I measure the degree of rotation of the second image with respect to the first image in `Python`?

I looked around, but couldn't find a clear method to do that. For instance, I checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731947/detect-angle-and-rotate-an-image-in-python), but when I applied it on my non-rotated image, I got an angle of around -70 returned, while I expected 0. For another rotated image I have it also gave me the wrong angle. Apart from that I would like to compare the rotated image with an some reference image, which I believe the code doesn't include.

I also checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877626/calculate-angle-of-rotation-image-wrt-another-image/37878122), but couldn't grasp the idea of how I can measure the rotation with respect to the original (reference) image.

Thanks for your kind support

Comment: Are the images `rotated` exactly on the center, or can this vary?

Comment: Post some sample images.

Comment: @user1767754 Yes, I believe that most of my images are rotated on the center.

Comment: @zindarod Sure, I have added a sample image.

Comment: Add the non rotated one as well.... and make sure those are real data. One method would be using `SIFT` algorithm to track features and see how far they went apart.

Comment: Search for "image alignment in opencv" to find a lot of tutorials for this. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086062/align-images-in-opencv) answer has a lot of suggestions for the various ways of accomplishing this. The two general methods are *dense* optical flow, which looks to align each pixel, and *sparse* optical flow, which looks to align features. Feature based methods are faster and more robust to different illumination conditions. If your images are *purely* rotated, then you can simply rotate your image in a loop and do template matching.